# Is it possible to REFRESH a div without LOADING a page into it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

SOLVED -SORT OF---

window.location.reload(); in my code where i have the submit button close the div, worked.

```
// Collapse Panel on submit
$("div#panel").on('submit', function() {
window.location.reload();
$("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
$("#toggle a").toggle();

return false;
});
```

I keep searching for this answer and i get more frustrated every time.

Scenario:

1. i have a div that slides down for login purposes (jquery, css).
2. the login form itself in that div is initially dynamically created with PHP ( by if else statement based on value in SESSIONS - PHP echo loads the form).

3.if i put in the correct login and click submit, i have the div close (jquery on(submit)) so that the user can see the page. The page loads dynamic content from a php file using xajax/PHP functions.

4.PROBLEM -  if i click to re-open the div it still shows my login form.(because the page has not reloaded). BUT my on page navbar done with xajax/PHP reloads to show the correct menu functions.

1. my problem is that i want the div to REFRESH  after submission, or on any event change if that helps, so that it sees the NEW SESSION data and adjusts accordingly. I DO NOT WANT TO LOAD ANOTHER HTML PAGE INTO THE DIV, so load(whatever.html) IS NOT WHAT I WANT.

if i refresh the whole page using f5 after i login, and pull down the div, the login form will not be there because my SESSIONS now states that im a logged in user and no longer a guest that needs to login. and the div isnt just for login, it will house other links and shortcuts, so it would be used while your logged in throughout your visit.

index.php

```
<div id="left" class="left">

         <?php      if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        if($_SESSION["admin"] == "1") {
            echo "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS AN ADMIN";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
        echo "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS A USER";
    }

    else { echo  '<form class="clearfix" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="javascript:void(null)" onsubmit="xajax_login(xajax.getFormValues(\'loginForm\'));">';
```

slide.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");

}); 

// Collapse Panel
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");

}); 

// Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
$("#toggle a").click(function () {
    $("#toggle a").toggle();
}); 


// Collapse Panel on submit
$("div#panel").on('submit', function() {
$("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
$("#toggle a").toggle();
return false;
});
// if there is an error, close div and allow link on main content page to be clicked to reopen div
$("#content").on('click', "#tryAgain",function() {
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $("#toggle a").toggle();
}); });
```

Comment: what do you want the div to load?

Comment: i dont understand whey you would 'click to re-open the div' once you are already logged in.

Comment: the div currently has a login form, registration form, and will have a quick search form for the site... so i would like it to be usable for hiding quick access things, if i cant get this then ill just have it lock closed once your logged in..

Comment: the div is loaded by sessions, meaning if i refesh the page after logging in, the login form is replaced by things useful to someone who is logged in, but all that data is just in an if else statement in the main page, so if im a user and logged in and i open the panel it wont show a login form. i just need it to refresh after i login so that happens... i really dont want to have it refresh the whole page, but if i have to i will.

Comment: ok you can use jquery to populate the div, with or with out ajax, on any event  jquery can trigger from

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to be acomplished even with pure JavaScript, no need of jQuery.

Just make one JS function that resets the input fields in the form or the div and call it every time when you need to "refresh" the content of the div or the form.

If you paste the div definition we can give you more specific advice accompanied with JS code that actually do this.

Comment: im trying to sort out which code would best help you guys to assist, gimme a min and ill see what i can do.

Comment: ok so there is the basics...   form located in my php page, js page makes the div slide, form is loaded based on if your logged in or not, form calls php function to checkout all the loading and all that jazz

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you load values into the form when the page loads, it makes sense they'd be there when the form is submitted via ajax.  What you really need to do is clear the form values when the div is 'closed' in the first place.

```
$(#formselector).on('submit',function(){
    //your ajax login and page load code

   //then:
   $('#formselector').find('input').attr('value','');

});
```

## UPDATE

Based on your comment, what you really need to do is check to see if the user is really logged in before popping the form in the first place.  There are a few techniques to do this, but what I'd recommend is in your php script that your form submits to, before processing the login, check your `$_COOKIE` variable to see if the user is recognized.  This also requires modification of your login script to make sure it stores user data in a `$_COOKIE`, similar to how it stores data in the `&_SESSION` variable.

At that point, your php script will deliver two different responses based on the user state, and your javascript code that launches the form drop down would check to see if it gets the "user not found" response before showing the login form.

Comment: that just empties the values from the form. my concern isn't that the values are still there, its that the form is still there...

Comment: well if you wanted to 'refresh' the page, and that's it's initial state, then the form WOULD still be there. If the only thing in that div is the form, and you don't want the form, why are you worried about re-opening the div in the first place?

Comment: if i refresh the whole page using f5 after i login, and pull down the div, the login form will not be there because my SESSIONS now states that im a logged in user and no longer a guest that needs to login.

and the div isnt just for login, it will house other links and shortcuts, so it would be used while your logged in throughout your visit.

Comment: `$('#formselector').remove();` //remove from DOM altogeather ?

Comment: ahhhh.  Now that is avery different problem from what you described, and you may want to consider making THAT simple explanation your question.  If you do so, I will assist you.

Comment: cookies. oh fun. looks like ill be doing a LOT more hair pulling out tonight.  My only frustration is that the "content" div which is called when you screw up on the form, there is an existing navigation div that updates once you login... so i was assuming i could figure out whats making it refresh, but i think its just because that is done in pure PHP. Ill learn about cookies and see where that takes me.

Comment: basically when i login, everything on the site updates to show the new data based on being logged in, EXCEPT THIS SLIDING DIV...

Comment: Also, i could deal with the whole div not refreshing if the open close link wasnt still there for soemone to reopen it and see the crappy coding job, lol. because if i refresh the page after logging in, i have those all set to be gone and replaced with navbar links...

Answer (score 0):

To just refresh the content of a particular div, use the follwing:

$("#abc").load(location.href + " #abc>*", "")

where #abc is for the div to be targeted.